# expects parameter

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

here im getting problem with my join query..i dont know where is the problem whether my query is wrong or whatelse but the error its giving is

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in     C:\xampp\htdocs\project\teacher\courses-list.php on line 46
```

heres my code please mend the code i cudnt find the problem.. :(
     courses-list.php

```
<?php
 if ($_SESSION["isteacher"])
{

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

}
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT courses.id AS cid, courses.title, courses.description,    courses.subjects-id, subjects.id AS sid, subjects.subjectname AS sname FROM courses,    subjects WHERE (courses.subjects-id==subjects.id)");
echo "<table border='1'> <br />
<tr>
<th>ID:</th>
<th>Course Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Subject-ID</th>
<th>EDIT</th>
<th>DELETE</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // this is the error line
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='courses-edit.php?id=" . $row['id']."'>EDIT</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='courses-delete.php?id=" . $row['id']."'>DELETE</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your SQL is wrong - the comparison operator is `=`, not `==`

Comment: yes it was... but still the problem is there...its giving error on this line     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: Could you try echoing out your SQL, and running it straight in the database? That should give you a more meaningful error message.

Answer (score 1):

here is the error

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT courses.id AS cid, courses.title, courses.description,    courses.subjects-id, subjects.id AS sid, subjects.subjectname AS sname FROM courses,    subjects WHERE (courses.subjects-id==subjects.id)");
```

should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT courses.id AS cid, courses.title, courses.description,    courses.subjects-id, subjects.id AS sid, subjects.subjectname AS sname FROM courses,    subjects WHERE (courses.subjects-id=subjects.id)");
```

the error portion is

```
subjects WHERE (courses.subjects-id==subjects.id)");
        here is the error ---------^^--------sould be =
```

also [**please avoid even dont use the `mysql_*` even the php manual show the message about that use the mysqli or PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: The SQL is still  wrong since you have a column name with a - inside and you did not quote it with backticks.

Comment: With such ridiculously long lines of code, you should explicitly point out the error so we don't have to run it through `diff`.

Comment: @registered user yes this was the mistake i made but still its giving the same error :(

Comment: @dweeves i just didnt get what are u talking about sorry for bothering u

Comment: you have a minus sign in the name of your column "subjects-id" , which is not very common and is a bit error prone. you might still use this weird column name in your sql by quoting it \`courses\`.\`subject-id\`

Comment: owww... actually yes.. this is the field name in db aswell... i've changed it now...but th error is still there :(

Comment: You need to fix your application to check for erros from `mysql_query()` and display the SQL error message, it will tell you where your syntax error is. It's not productive to keep coming back here after you fix each one of them -- that's your job as a programmer.

Comment: @Barmar thanx for giving me right suggestion :) its done now.. Thnx anyways